# Bounds of the difference of a bounded band-limited function

Tags: inequality, signal-processing

For continuous signals (functions) we have that Bernstein inequality holds:
$$
 \left|\frac{\mathrm{d}f(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\right| \le 2AB\pi 
$$
where  $A=\sup|f(t)|$  and $B$ is the bandwidth of $f(t)$.

**My question is**: does there exists a similar a relationship for discrete function $x[n]$ like this one
$$
|x[n] - x[n-1]| \le\   \mu W,
$$
where

- $
  X[k] = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {x[n]{e^{ - j\frac{{2\pi }}{N}nk}}} 
  $
  is the DFT (Discrete Fourier transform) of $x[n]$ and
- $X[k]=0$ for $k > W$?

Comment: Hi and welcome: your question seems interesting so, in order to help other users help you, consider the possibility of adding more context. For example, why the question is interesting in your opinion? What did you tried to solve it?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Because, in practical terms, when we want to use Bernstein's inequality, we derive neither derivatives nor Fourier integral.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/52953/4298).